# async action filter in MVC for async controller methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, aop

Let me prefix first that there are already two questions from Stack Overflow with accepted answers that async action filters are not supported:

[Async action filter in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482338/async-action-filter-in-mvc-4)

[Calling Async Methods in Action Filters in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246030/calling-async-methods-in-action-filters-in-mvc-5)

So, I'm looking for a 'work-around'. This is what I currently do in my WebApi application:

```
public class MessageLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await LogRequestInfo(request);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        await LogResponseInfo(response);
        return response;
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to log the request and log the response as a cross cutting concern. How can I do this in MVC? Is it even possible? I see two posts with a possible solution... has anyone used it? Does it work? Should I even go down this path? Are there alternatives? I'm really hesitant to adopt either approach for fear of breaking something in our application.

1) Implement a custom AsyncControllerActionInvoker

http://ayende.com/blog/163170/building-async-unit-of-work-with-mvc-4

2) Create and Async Controller Base Class, uses the "ParallelExtensionsExtras" library (whatever that is), and overrides some of the BeginExecute, EndExecute methods.

[Perform Async operation asp.net mvc outside of the action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945548/perform-async-operation-asp-net-mvc-outside-of-the-action)

Comment: ASP.NET vNext *will* support async filters on its version of MVC. So, another option is to just log synchronously for now (inefficient, but it works), and then upgrade to a proper async filter when ASP.NET vNext comes out.

Comment: When you say do it synchronously, do you mean that I have to change my controller methods to be synchronous too? All our action methods are async at the moment, and I don't want to be telling the team to re-write all the code to make it synchronous again with threads to call the async code.

Comment: No, you can just make the `Log*Info` methods called from the filter synchronous; the controller methods can stay asynchronous.

Comment: I've recently [published a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hydrogen.Extensions.Mvc5.Async) that adds proper support for async filters (heavily based on code in from [ASP.NET MVC Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)).

Source is also available here: https://github.com/jdaigle/Hydrogen.Extensions.Mvc5.